# how to get hash value from URL by codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I have URL like this `http://localhost/site/section/80#10`

and the function section like this

```
function  section(id = null){
    echo id;
}
```

The question is how can i get #10 from URL ?

Answer (score 4):

You can't.  The hash portion of the URL isn't actually sent to the server.

Comment: thank you, i think to pass additional value to function instead, is better.

Comment: You can enable query strings in CI - sometimes uri segment code gets to be more trouble than it's worth.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the hash using javascript's `window.location.hash` and send it to the server with ajax.

A jQuery example:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://site.com/controller/method_that_does_something_with_hash',
    data: {
        hash: window.location.hash
    },
    success: function(response){
        // do something here with whatever the server responded with
    }
});
```